# How convert an embedded Neo4j graph db to GraphML with Python?

Tags: python, neo4j, graphml, neo4j.py

I want to store my embedded Neo4j Graph db to GraphML to draw it with a tool like yEd.

I'm managing the graph db with python27.

Does any body knows a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to do it outside of the process -- which means you'll need to shut down your existing process working on the embedded database and restart when finished with the export-- you can use [Gremlin](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin) to do it. Here's the commands you'll need:

```
g = new Neo4jGraph("/YOUR/GRAPH/DIRECTORY")
writer = new GraphMLWriter(g)
out = new FileOutputStream("/YOUR/GRAPHML/file.graphml")
writer.outputGraph(out)
writer.setNormalize(true)
out.close()
```

This will create a nice pretty graphml file that is suitable for reading into a tool like [Gephi](http://gephi.org/) or [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/).

If you need to export the graph in-process you'll need to use something like jython to run your python scripts and then use the above commands by importing the objects from `com.tinkerpop.blueprints`.

Comment: that seems really nice, but unfortunately when I try to do this, neo4j is initialized, but fails to start :S
Does gremlin work well with the python-embedded 1.6 neo4j edition?

Answer (score 0):

If neo4j.py does not support exporting to GraphML format, or for any reason you cannot do that with Neo4j + Java, you'll have to write a custom exporter.

With some simple hacks you can accomplish that with [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/index.html), which supports importing from/exporting to GraphML. Just figure a way to import your Neo4j graph into NetworkX and then export it directly to GraphML.